# Concatenating with Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, text, replace

I have a JQuery function that grabs the URL path and adds it as a body class as such:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var pathSlashesReplaced = pathname.replace(/\//g, " ");
var pathSlashesReplacedNoFirstDash = pathSlashesReplaced.replace(" ","");
var newClass = pathSlashesReplacedNoFirstDash.replace(/\(\d*\)/g, '').replace(/\s/, '-');

    $("body").addClass(newClass);
    if ( $("body").attr("class") == "") 
    {   

        $("body").addClass("class");

    }
```

.. so if the url is something like /myapp/user/list, the body class ends up as:

```
<body class="myapp-user list">
```

The issue is I would like to have all three words with dashes so it should be:

```
<body class="myapp-user-list">
```

.. and then I can theme using the CSS:

```
.myapp-user-list {

}
```

I am pretty sure there is an issue with my RegEx but I cannot figure out where. I tried various text functions but then the problem was that it grabbed all the text from the page and put that in as the body class:

```
var text = $(this).text();
var newClass  = $.trim(text.replace(/\(\d*\)/g, '').toLowerCase()).replace(/\s/, '-');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
var newClass = location.pathname.split('/').join('-').replace(/(^-|-$)/g,''),
    $body = $("body").addClass(newClass);

if ($body.attr("class") == "") {   
    $body.addClass("class");
}
```

I would avoid the class name `class`. It could give problems.

Comment: Great answer, but you still need to trim the leading "/" to prevent the unwanted leading "-" before the split.

Comment: How about `...pathname.replace(/^\/+/, '').split...`

Comment: This is a cool approach and with the addtion of @MarkM's code, it works great.  I think this is more extensible say if the patth is deeper or shorter

Comment: Answer edited - thanks @Mark M - I opted to convert all `/` to `-` first then to strip leading and trailing `-`. This is slightly simpler as it avoids the need to escape `/` in the regExp. I don't think the `+` quantifier is necessary as `//` will never appear in a path.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: Happy to help.  Didn't want to be a hit-and-run criticiser.  Your points are well-taken - I didn't take the time to really hone my answer very well and just went with the main idea once I got something that worked.  It's something I'm working on to improve the quality of my answers.

Comment: @Mark M, your interjection was exemplary.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `g` modifier to the second replace to replace all white spaces and not just the first.

```
var newClass = pathSlashesReplacedNoFirstDash.replace(/\(\d*\)/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '-');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that applying these two regexps will do the job.

```
"/\//-/g"   Will change all slashes to -
"/-//"      Will only remove the first -
```